# Xcode 7 framework caching? How to update a framework

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, frameworks

I've been modifying the opencv framework and rebuilding it for use in an Xcode 7 project. None of the modifications are reflected in the project that uses the framework. I've tried deleting the framework and rebuilding the project. The project builds fine, even when the framework has been deleted.

Does Xcode cache frameworks? I've tried deleting the "Derived Data" folder as well. The project still builds. The project is a simple one built to test the framework.

How do I get a framework built outside the project to update?

Comment: More info:
I am very puzzled. I tried deleting all libraries and frameworks generated by opencv using "sudo make uninstall", deleting "Derived Data" folder, and "Clean"ing the project. It still complies and links fine. Where are the opencv object files coming from?